# Консоль (терминал) для оконного приложения как в WebStorm

Tags: javascript, .net, node.js

господа и дамы. Есть не совсем стандартный таск (по крайней мере я его таковым считаю), нужно сделать терминал (консоль) для оконного приложения. Примером может служить web storm или atom... Не суть. Дело в том что я не понимаю даже в каком направлении копать, посредством чего это можно реализовать - js, node, .net.... Возможно кто-то сталкивался раньше с подобными задачами и может натолкнуть на мысль. Будет полезна любая информация. Заранее премного благодарен!

Comment: напишите, для какого приложения надо сделать консоль (веб-клиент, веб-сервер, толстый клиент). допустим решение ниже подходит только для веб-клиента с поддержкой typescript (доп. компиляция на node.js). также нужно знать какие конкретно оконные фреймвоки используются (winforms, bootstrap...). может хотите включить консоль для стороннего приложения.

Comment: @АлексейОбухов приложение типа фотошопа, winforms, bootstrap - отсутствуют, написано на ангуляре. и собственно это всё что могу сказать =(

Answer (score 2):

Если писать с нуля - задача довольно объёмная. Я бы посоветовал обратить внимание на вот этот проект https://github.com/xtermjs/xterm.js/, возможно его использование облегчит решение вашей задачи(по крайней мере со стороны фронтэнда).

Comment: большое спасибо, изучаю документацию.

Comment: отличная вещь, но не совсем то что мне нужно. 
Xterm.js не является терминальным приложением, которое вы можете загрузить и использовать на своем компьютере.
а мне напротив нужно интегрировать его в своё приложение, но во всяком случае большое спасибо.